# How can I use ssh on Windows with Dart and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ssh

The package ssh2 does not seem to have Windows support.
And Stackoverflow doesn't seem to like short questions.

Answer (score 0):

use dartssh2/dartssh2.dart';
here how to connect :

Future serversChecker(context) async {

```
  for (var server in serverList) {
    String serverIp = server['ipAddress'];
    int port = int.parse(server['port']);
    String userName = server['userName'];
    String password = server['password'];

    try {
      final socket = await SSHSocket.connect(serverIp, port);

      final client = SSHClient(
        socket,
        username: userName,
        onPasswordRequest: () => password,
      );
```